# Convert Custom Type From Oracle to C#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I have some oracle sql code that has types specified and returns them like such (please excuse the simplified example).

```
create or replace type varchar2Row as table of varchar2(1000);
/
create or replace type varchar2Matrix as table of varchar2Row;
/
create or replace function get_myTableResult(in_name varchar2) return varchar2Matrix is
  l_result varchar2Matrix := varchar2Matrix();
begin
  l_result.extend(2);
  l_result(1) := varchar2Row(in_name, in_name || '1', in_name || '2');
  l_result(2) := varchar2Row(in_name, '1' || in_name, '2' || in_name);
  return l_result;
end;
```

I want to be able to call this from the C# layer and then cast the varchar2Matrix to 2d array of strings. Would such a thing be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define classes for UDTs:

```
[OracleCustomTypeMapping("<schema>.VARCHAR2MATRIX")]
public class Varchar2Matrix : CustomCollectionTypeBase<Varchar2Matrix, Varchar2Row>
{
}

[OracleCustomTypeMapping("<schema>.VARCHAR2ROW")]
public class Varchar2Row : CustomCollectionTypeBase<Varchar2Row, string>
{
}

public abstract class CustomCollectionTypeBase<TType, TValue> : CustomTypeBase<TType>, IOracleArrayTypeFactory where TType : CustomTypeBase<TType>, new()
{
    [OracleArrayMapping()]
    public TValue[] Values;

    public override void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection connection, IntPtr pointerUdt)
    {
        OracleUdt.SetValue(connection, pointerUdt, 0, Values);
    }

    public override void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection connection, IntPtr pointerUdt)
    {
        Values = (TValue[])OracleUdt.GetValue(connection, pointerUdt, 0);
    }

    public Array CreateArray(int elementCount)
    {
        return new TValue[elementCount];
    }

    public Array CreateStatusArray(int elementCount)
    {
        return new OracleUdtStatus[elementCount];
    }
}

public abstract class CustomTypeBase<T> : IOracleCustomType, IOracleCustomTypeFactory, INullable where T : CustomTypeBase<T>, new()
{
    private bool _isNull;

    public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
    {
        return new T();
    }

    public abstract void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection connection, IntPtr pointerUdt);

    public abstract void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection connection, IntPtr pointerUdt);

    public bool IsNull
    {
        get { return this._isNull; }
    }

    public static T Null
    {
        get { return new T { _isNull = true }; }
    }
}
```

And then invoke the function, for instance:

```
using (var connection = new OracleConnection("connection string"))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.BindByName = true;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT get_myTableResult(:p) FROM dual";

        var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
        parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameter.ParameterName = "p";
        parameter.Value = "string value";
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        var = result command.ExecuteScalar();

        // access the data from the result object
    }
}
```